# How to set custom Keyboard to all EditText in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have created my own keyboard and want to set it on all EditTexts in my app. Is there a way to do it with xml attributes (probably not, or)?
How to do it programmatically?

Comment: what type of keyboard you looking for only numbers or keys also

Comment: @Ashish  I created my own. It contains numbers. Like a calculator keyboard

Comment: Any update for this post?